# ‎Show that the rank of this matrix is one.‎

Tags: linear-algebra

‎Let $D$ be a division ring and ‎$n \geq 2$. Suppose ‎‎$A, B \in M_n(D)$ and ‎$X, Y \in M_{n\times 1}(D)$ are non-zero vectors ‎such ‎that $AX = BX = 0$ ‎and $Y^tA = Y^tB = 0$‎. If we put $M = XY^t$ then we have $AM = MA = 0$ and $BM = MB = 0$‎. I ‎have ‎to ‎show ‎$\operatorname{rank} ‎M=1$.‎

Comment: What definition of rank are you using?